# I got warning which I couldn't understand

Tags: iphone, sdk

When I compiled my app I got this warning and I couldn't understand it.

```
/Users/imac/Desktop/MyApp/RechercherView.xib:44:0 This bar button item's style is set to 'plain'. This configuration is not supported when in a navigation item.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Plain` is for when a bar button item is on a tab bar, it means there is no border at all and you just see the item.  This is not supported on a nav bar and they must be `bordered`. If you wish to get the appearance of an item without a border, you should make your own custom `UIButton` to put up there

Comment: oups, the info button was setted to plain style, i changed it to bordered style and the warnings disappear, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. go to the navigation item
2. select the navigation Bar button
3. just change the bar button item in attribute inspector
4. style from plain to rounded or done