# Unsupported configuration plain style unsupported in a navigation item

Tags: xcode4.2

When i try to add a button to a navigation bar, i got this warning:

```
unsupported configuration plain style unsupported in a navigation item
```

Concerning the Plain style, i don't find it in interface builder since i moved to Xcode4.2.

EDIT:
@Michael: here is what Xcode look like for me:
[image]

I have not the arrow to the left, is there any thing missing there?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [i got warning which i couldn't understand](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5612187)

Comment: that was my post, yes, but in Xcode 4.2, i don't find how to change the style of the button from Plan to bordered.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Is the button you added a "Bar Button Item"?

[image: Bar Button Item]

Comment: oups, it's a Rounded button, may be that's why ;)

Comment: If you change the style of the bar button item that contains the rounded rect button to "Bordered", you can get rid of this error

Comment: what if I do not want the button to be bordered. I want it plain style

Comment: Setting the button to bordered removed the style attribute. -                        before: <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" style="plain" id="SH5-3r-aDm">
after: <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" id="SH5-3r-aDm">

Comment: Instead of `bordered` style I used `Done` style in Xcode 5.1 and solved my problem without having to use the bordered style.

Comment: What are the ramifications of simply ignoring this warning?

Answer (score 6):

1. go to the navigation item
2. select the navigation Bar button
3. just change the bar button item in attribute inspector

   ```
   style - bordered
   ```

   and then run the program warning is not showing

Comment: I had a UIView instead of a barbutton and just had to change it to bordered and it worked.  Thank you.